# Java extended properties configuration

Tags: java

I am looking for implementation of properties configuration where properties are considered in the following order (or similar):

- Command line arguments.
- Java System properties(System.getProperties()).
- OS environment variables.
- Application properties outside of your packaged jar.

It means there would be `application.properties` file. This can be overwritten by OS environment variables and so on. Command line arguments overwrites all previous properties.

Comment: ...and the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

That is actually the way Springs [PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) is working, if you provide different PropertySources in the disired priority.

Unfortunatly it does only work with the Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("settings.properties"));
        properties.load(input);
        String ipAddress = properties.getProperty("ip");
```

And save it when you exit for exemple

```
 File f = new File("settings.properties");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    properties.setProperty("ip", ipAddress);
    properties.store(out, "properties");
```